# Yii2: Perform action on session timeout

Tags: php, session, yii2

I use [Yii2 sessions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session) for storing session data for guest users.

During sessions there are files generated in `@runtime` directory. These files are named with a database id (e.g. `234.pdf`).

When a user selects something, the selection is saved in the db, stored in the session and a file is generated:

```
$model->save();
file_put_contents($model->id.".pdf", ...);
Yii::$app->session->set("model_id",$model->id);
```

When a session expires the sesseion related files should be removed. The database contents have to be kept for statistical reasons.

How do I get recognized when a session expires?

Comment: If you know when last login was, you can e.g. delete file after 1d with crone jobs

Comment: I just ave guest users which do not login at all. So attaching to login prcedures is no valid option

Comment: Well, decide when you can safely delete files. E.g. every midnight or after week of creation of file...

Comment: i dont quiet get the idea of guest user session expiring ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam added sample code and some explanation to the question

Comment: i get that part, what i am trying to understand is when the user is already a guest what makes you say that the session session expires?

Comment: you might be talking about session timeout? instead

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The gutest user can start a task an perform some actions. After 10 minutes of incativity the session should be killed.

Comment: i would say you would have to mainly work with `session.cookie_lifetime` and `session.gc_maxlifetime` and implement your our session timeout, and to do it in Yii you must know how to do it in core php first, [here](https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/08/implementing-session-timeout-with-php/) is good read that can help you out in first understanding why you need to implement your own session timeout and then how to do that, it is a bit broad question so i thought you should implement and then if you get stuck somewhere we can look into it.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I now understand that there is no Yii2 support for events like "sesson timeout" that can be used here. I will have to write cronjobs for cleaning up files from time to time.

Comment: yes, you can do that via cron job too, that article also covers that part too

Answer (score 0):

`Yii` does not have configurable session event handlers, in your case I would create own specific session handler extending PHP's built-in [**SessionHandler**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php).

```
namespace app\components;

class CustomSessionHandler extends \SessionHandler
{
    public function destroy($sessionId)
    {
        // here you could implement your custom requirements
        return parent::destroy($sessionId);
    }
}
```

and here is your configuration

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        'handler' => \app\components\CustomSessionHandler::class
    ],
    ...
];
```

Comment: When is the Method ```destroy()```executed exactely? Can you provide some more insights to your solution?  I don't want to call  it manually. It should be bound to the Session context

Comment: the destroy has nothing to do with session timeout or expiry, this answer is more likely for manually logging out, if i am not wrong about it